# How to select from a table that has been joined with same model/class/table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to get a count of how many subcontacts every contact has.

```
Class Contacts  
has_many :subcontacts, class_name: "Contact",foreign_key: "supercontact_id" 
belongs_to :supercontact, class_name:"Contact"
```

And here's the activerecord part i have so far that's roughly what i'm trying to do.

```
Contact.joins{subcontacts.outer}.select(subcontacts.count as subcontact_count)
```

I think the problem is that the joins portion is looking for a association name and the select part is looking for a table name. The trouble is that the table name is the same table... What's the best way to do this so that it stays as a relation or using SQL so that we can minimize the number of queries so that it isn't an N+1 problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
results = Contact.joins(:subcontacts).select("count(subcontacts.id) as count, contacts.id").group("contacts.id")
```

and count can be fetched as

```
results.map do |result|
  "Contact ID: #{result.id} - Subcontacts Count: #{result['count']}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This probably works, but ideally i'd like to keep it as an activerecord relation. I simplified the code pasted here, but a lot of it depends on the results being a relation, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Contacts.all.each do |contact|
  puts contact.name =>  contact.subcontacts.count
end

OR

Contacts.all.map{|contact| [contact.name => contact.subcontacts.count]}
```

The above will provide you the hash like answer{contact_name => subcontacts.count}